# Query for only 1 returned row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, pivot

I am looking for assistance in understanding how I can fix this SQL query which returns a count based on a supply and demand matrix. I want only one record returned, however the query is returning a record per value, and leaving the rest of the columns for that row as 0's.

The SQL Server query looks like this.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Apple' AND FruitDemand = 'Peach' THEN COUNT(ISNULL(FruitID, 0)) ELSE 0 END As Box1,
CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Apple' AND FruitDemand = 'Orange' THEN COUNT(ISNULL(FruitID, 0)) ELSE 0 END As Box2,
CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Apple' AND FruitDemand = 'Pear' THEN COUNT(ISNULL(FruitID, 0)) ELSE 0 END As Box3,
CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Apple' AND FruitDemand = 'Apple' THEN COUNT(ISNULL(FruitID, 0)) ELSE 0 END As Box4,
CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Pear' AND FruitDemand = 'Peach' THEN COUNT(ISNULL(FruitID, 0)) ELSE 0 END As Box5,
CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Pear' AND FruitDemand = 'Orange' THEN COUNT(ISNULL(FruitID, 0)) ELSE 0 END As Box6,
CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Pear' AND FruitDemand = 'Pear' THEN COUNT(ISNULL(FruitID, 0)) ELSE 0 END As Box7,
CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Pear' AND FruitDemand = 'Apple' THEN COUNT(ISNULL(FruitID, 0)) ELSE 0 END As Box8
FROM FruitList
GROUP BY FruitID, FruitSupply, FruitDemand
```

The returned result set looks like this.

```
Box1    Box2    Box3    Box4    Box5    Box6    Box7    Box8
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       10      0       0       0       0
```

The result that I'm looking for would be:

```
Box1    Box2    Box3    Box4    Box5    Box6    Box7    Box8
2       1       1       10      1       1       0       0
```

Is there a way to fix this or have I gone down the complete wrong path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregate functions around the `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Apple' AND FruitDemand = 'Peach'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Box1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Apple' AND FruitDemand = 'Orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Box2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Apple' AND FruitDemand = 'Pear'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Box3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Apple' AND FruitDemand = 'Apple'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Box4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Pear'  AND FruitDemand = 'Peach'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Box5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Pear'  AND FruitDemand = 'Orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Box6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Pear'  AND FruitDemand = 'Pear'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Box7,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FruitSupply = 'Pear'  AND FruitDemand = 'Apple'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Box8
FROM FruitList
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Perfect and thank you. I have learned something today and very happy.